# Why does the talking zebra always address Candace as Kevin?

Tags: plot-explanation, phineas-and-ferb

In *[Phineas and Ferb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phineas_and_Ferb)*, we meet the talking zebra a lot and it's a character of Candace's imagination. But, why did it call Candace "Kevin"? That's a male name and has no relation to Candace. Is this some reference to any other show, etc.?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [Phineas and Ferb wikia](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Talking_Zebra#Background_Information):

> It is currently unknown why the Talking Zebra calls Candace "Kevin". Although, as revealed in the Phineas and Ferb The Movie: Across the 2nd Dimension, **Kevin may actually be the Candace of the Zebra's dimension**. However, how, or even why the zebra seems to cross dimensions is unknown.

[image: Notice the silhoutte]

Notice the silhouette of the image where it bears striking resemblance to Candace...

There is also a passing reference where the Zebra says "I voted for you Kevin!" with Candace's face...

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple references. We can say Easter Eggs.

Candace's last name is Flynn. Zebra calls her Kevin every time which makes her Kevin Flynn. There are some famous people with the same name.

1. [Kevin Flynn](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Kevin_Flynn) is the main protagonist of *[Tron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron_(franchise))* franchise.
2. [Kevin Flynn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Flynn_(politician)) is a Canadian politician. (This could be a reference to "I voted for you Kevin" in [Nerds of a Feather](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Nerds_of_a_Feather)). This is continued by showing a newspaper clipping Kevin wins election in the song "Brand New Reality".

[image: Zebra talking to Candace]

Answer (score -3):

Zebra mistakens Candace for Kevin. Simple as that.
Example when I standing in crowd and say something to a guy that similarly resembles San Huan De Luglio je Capueira, because he just looks that way.

Comment: Wrong answer. Neither Zebra nor Candace were not standing in the crowd. There is a distance of a foot between them.

Comment: No, that ain't my point. My point that Candace looks like Kevin to Zebra. Though to me Candace always looked like Jordano.